# Extending Dev Tools to display response headers

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing a Chrome Extension for DevTools that should create a new panel and for each of the HTTP request processed by Devtools, I need to display in this panel the HTTP headers of the response.

So far I have managed to get the following that creates the Panel and display the requests URL:

```
var PanelWindow;

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
    function(request) {
      PanelWindow.document.body.appendChild(
      document.createTextNode(request.request.url+
      " "+request.response.headers[0]));
      PanelWindow.document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
);


chrome.devtools.panels.create("Pascal", "icon.png", "panel.html",
  function(extensionPanel) {
    extensionPanel.onShown.addListener(function(panelWindow) {
        PanelWindow = panelWindow;
    });
});
```

I can't find the complete documentation on *Request.Response* object. Could you point me to the documentation and/or share the code to access the request.response headers ?

Thanks in advance,
Pascal

Answer (score 0):

Responding to myself, I have found the answer from a sample extension:

```
var hdrs = har_entry.response.headers;
for (var i = 0; i < hdrs.length; i++) {
    var hdr = hdrs[i];
    PanelWindow.document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(hdr.name + ": " + hdr.value));
    PanelWindow.document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```